# Django - generate a unique suffix to an uploaded file (uuid is cut and django adds another suffix)

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload, django-storage

I'm going to use DigitalOcean Spaces as a file storage and I want to add suffixes to uploaded filenames for two reasons:

- impossible to guess file url with bruteforce
- ensure it is unique, as I'm not sure if Django can check for filename uniqueness on S3

This is the method:

```
def cloudfile_upload_to(instance, filename):
    path = storage_path_service.StoragePathService.cloud_dir(instance.cloud)
    filename, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    _uuid = uuid.uuid4()
    return os.path.join(path, f"{filename}-{uuid}{ext}")
```

in the code:

```
path == "user/11449_bacccbe4-6794-42e3-89c3-5045b024fa11/income/1541/cloud"
filename, ext = "webp", ".webp"
uuid == "f8851579-3aa6-403b-bc08-86923d72e80b"
```

When I check the file it is in a correct dir, but the filename is:

```
"webp-527846f0-4284-4e_YvqcSrf.webp"
```

AS you can see, uuid is cut and Django adds it's own suffix. How to make it work?

Comment: Could you add your code where you're uploading the file?

Comment: @DMalan I'm uploading the file using Django admin, file is just `file = models.FileField(upload_to=cloudfile_upload_to)`

Comment: Is `{uuid}` a typo? Should it not be `{_uuid}`?

Comment: What is `max_length` set to for your storage object? What kind of storage are you using? The Django docs say that if a path is too long, it will be truncated, and random characters will be appended to the filename to make sure the file is unique. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.get_available_name

Comment: As @DMalan said, you have a typo at {uuid}. With that, the filename will be `webp-527846f0-4284-.webp`. And most likely, you uploaded the same file more than once. So Django already handled the filename by adding a suffix (`4e_YvqcSrf`).